# Question about printer repairing permissions

Tags: permission

Tried installing printer driver software. There was some message, that might have been about "software for the printer was installed incorrectly", then asked if I want to repair the thing, I agreed and it started repairing permissions. In the end it still didn't properly work.

The question I have is - what does repairing permissions mean in this context? I read articles and definitions and don't get it in this context. Did it mean the installer simply moved the driver under Mac's command or something?
Normal Mac thing, nothing to worry about?

Answer (score 1):

Fixing permissions simply means that macOS is going through it's files and ensuring that all the files have the correct ownership and permissions (to read/write/execute).

For more detailed explanation on permissions, have a look at [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/195912/how-when-and-why-to-repair-disk-permissions-on-your-mac/).

Usually, when something isn't working right, "fixing permissions" solves the problem because the system process that handles the operation (like printing) didn't have the permissions to access the necessary files.

In your case, it sounds like you have the wrong printer driver.

Comment: This is one of the articles I actually read. :) I understood what it means to fix permissions using Disk Utility (or not with new version that disabled it), but i couldn't figure out what it meant during installation. So my Mac was checking if this driver works, found it can't get it to work and that was just that - incompatibility issue? It is not a sign of anything malicious going on? Sorry, seeing word "fixing" got me nervous. :D "Correct ownership" in this case does not hopefully mean malicious outside third party access that needs to be removed?

Comment: Nothing malicious, this is a very common fix.  What you are describing sounds definitely like a compatibility issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, Allan! Guess Gutenprint did not mesh well with my old printer. I tried to give upvote but lack reputation now.

Comment: No worries.  Glad I could help.